# Query to update the nested list of Mongo document using Java

Tags: java, mongodb, mongodb-query, spring-mongodb, mongotemplate

I have the requirement to updated the nested list of a document, below is the query which I have written to pull and add the updated document to the nested list of document and which works fine in my shell window.

```
db.Masters.update({"subDepartmentList.labServiceList._id":"mnop"},
  {$pull: {"subDepartmentList.$.labServiceList" : {"_id" : "mnop"}}})

db.Masters.update({"_id":"DEPT5", "subDepartmentList.subDepartmentId":"SUBDEPT21"},
{$addToSet: {"subDepartmentList.$.labServiceList" :{
                "_id" : "mnop", 
                "departmentId" : "DEPT5",
                "subDepartmentId":"SUBDEPT21"  
                "labServiceCode" : "code456",
                "active":true
            }}})
```

In one of documentation, I read that $ operator is not supported for the deep nested list of the document, so I am not able to achieve the same. Can anyone guide me to achieve the same. I have also posted the other question before some days on this ([Updating document of nested list in Mongo DB](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45386667/updating-document-of-nested-list-in-mongo-db)), but did not get any answer, please guide me if you know any of those. Any suggestions would be appreciated.